# Pattern is not working for rewrite rule

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have 2 form of same URL (only difference is of last slash before `?`) and for that I need to create a single pattern (regular expression).  So same pattern could handle the both variations of URL.

- `products/dispenser/hand-towel?gclid=CPDv`
  and
- `products/dispenser/hand-towel/?gclid=CPDv`

I am trying to use below pattern, which is working fine for 1st URL but not working for 2nd URL.

- `^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$`

I tried few more below pattern but didn't get success.

- `^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+/.*| /?$)`
- `^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(^/?)$`
- `^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$`

By using a same pattern I want to get below Output, which I am getting through 1st URL.

- `{R:1} Dispenser`
- `{R:2} hand-towel?gclid=CPDv`

and from 2nd URL I need to get below output

- `{R:1} Dispenser`
- `{R:2} hand-towel/?gclid=CPDv`

I have 6 kind of URLs

1. `products/dispenser/hand-towel?gclid=CPDv`
2. `products/dispenser/hand-towel/?gclid=CPDv`
3. `products/dispenser/hand-towel`
4. `products/dispenser/hand-towel/hand-roll?gclid=CPDv`
5. `products/dispenser/hand-towel/hand-roll/?gclid=CPDv`
6. `products/dispenser/hand-towel/hand-roll`

---

So all above URLs will land on same page but if first 3 URLs will be hit then I need `dispenser` and `Hand-towel` as R1 and R2, and if the 4th, 5th and 6th URLs will be hit then I need `dispenser`, `hand-towel` and `hand-towel-roll` as R1, R2 and R3.

Whereas `^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$` pattern is only for 1 and 2 URLs as this pattern will not able to identify the R3 parameter for URL 4,5 and 6.

Whereas `^products\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/(.+)$` pattern is not working for 1st URL.

Comment: @Fallenhero: Thanks for your effort. 
But still some part is missing in the output, I have updated my question for better clarification, please see.

Answer (score 3):

Your Problem is the `$` at the end. This means `end of line` but you have `?gclid=CPDv` you still want to match.

See here: https://regex101.com/r/SkHXWH/2

The captured groups will give you the clue.

Why don't you just do this:

```
^products\/([^\/]+)\/(.+)$
           ^^^R1^^   ^R2^
```

this will give you the wanted output/capture groups

For your url as stated in comment

```
^products\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/(.+)$
           ^^^R1^^^  ^^^R2^^^  ^R3^
```

or with only 2 groups

```
^products\/([^\/]+)\/(?:[^\/]+)\/(.+)$
           ^^^R1^^^              ^R2^
```

Comment: Its seems that it is working for both URLs, but which part here is giving {R:1} and {R:2}, As I need to use these r1 and r2 for making the new URL.

Comment: What Do I need to add for this URL in Pattern. products/dispenser/hand-towel/hand-towel-roll/?gclid=CPDv